# Crystal Report always asking to enter parameter value

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am having a problem passing the combobox value to crystal report I am kinda newbie with the crystal report so I really need your help guys!

here is my code:

```
    dir = Path.GetFullPath(dir)
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim reportsfolder As String = Application.StartupPath + "\PrintArea\LoanProdReport.rpt"
    Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM ClientDatabase"
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(query, jonsqlcon)
    DA.Fill(DS)

    report.Load(reportsfolder)
    report.SetDatabaseLogon(dbSettingsAdder.TBUserID.Text, dbSettingsAdder.tbPassword.Text)
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("YearHeader")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = ComboBoxEx2.SelectedItem.ToString

    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

    report.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
    LoanProdRpt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
    LoanProdRpt.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    LoanProdRpt.ShowDialog()
```

and here is  the Screenshot of my Report
[image]

as you can see I am trying to pass the Combobox value into parameter YearHeader.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How silly of me, I just did it like this

```
    dir = Path.GetFullPath(dir)
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim reportsfolder As String = Application.StartupPath + "\PrintArea\LoanProdReport.rpt"
    Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM ClientDatabase"
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(query, jonsqlcon)
    DA.Fill(DS)

    report.Load(reportsfolder)
    report.SetDatabaseLogon(dbSettingsAdder.TBUserID.Text, dbSettingsAdder.tbPassword.Text)
    report.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))

    crParameterFieldDefinitions = report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("YearHeader")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = ComboBoxEx2.SelectedItem.ToString

    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

    LoanProdRpt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
    LoanProdRpt.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    LoanProdRpt.ShowDialog()
```